# Oracle copying rows into same table with different dates

Tags: sql, oracle, copy

I have a schedule where dates can cross midnight. In the example you can see dates for 08/23 & 08/24.

How can I copy these rows into the same table but with different dates.
For example the row with start_date 08/23 I want to be 08/28. The row with start_date 08/24 should be the next day 08/29.

Note the situation where the start_date=08/23 and end_date=08/24

Thanks in advance to all that answer.

```
Desired output

SCHEDULE_ID    LOCATION_ID    START_DATE    END_DATE
22    1    08232021 23:50:00    08232021 23:54:00
22    1    08232021 23:56:00    08242021 00:02:00
22    2    08242021 00:05:00    08242021 00:09:00

22    1    08282021 23:50:00    08282021 23:54:00
22    1    08282021 23:56:00    08292021 00:02:00
22    2    08292021 00:05:00    08292021 00:09:00


ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';

   create table schedule(
       schedule_id NUMBER(4),
       location_id number(4),
       start_date DATE,
       end_date DATE,
          check (start_date=trunc(start_date,'MI')),
        check (end_date=trunc(end_date,'MI'))
      );

   
   insert into schedule(
     schedule_id,
     location_id,
     start_date,
     end_date 
     )
        VALUES     (22,1,TO_DATE('2021/08/23 23:50:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),TO_DATE('2021/08/23 23:54:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));


   insert into schedule(
     schedule_id,
     location_id,
     start_date,
     end_date 
     )
        VALUES     (22,1,TO_DATE('2021/08/23 23:56:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),TO_DATE('2021/08/24 00:02:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));


   insert into schedule(
        schedule_id,
         location_id,
         start_date,
         end_date 
       )
       VALUES      (22,2,TO_DATE('2021/08/24 00:05:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
TO_DATE('2021/08/24 00:09:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this to generate more data, perhaps for testing?

It should be something like

```
insert into schedule
  select schedule_id, location_id, start_date + 5, end_date + 5
  from   schedule
;
```

The fact that some date intervals straddle over midnight is irrelevant.

Comment: thanks. Apologies if my post was misleading but there can be multiple schedules for a day.. What I'm trying to do is gather ALL the schedule rows for a date  and only copy them. I'm unsure about how to handle the schedules that cross midnight as I don't want to copy over part of a schedule. I need something a bit smarter. Perhaps something that finds all the rows for DATE, date+1 and copy those. I was thinking a MERGE so I don't get duplicate rows.

Comment: @Beefstu - Sorry, I don't understand. The solution I provided "copies" **all** the rows in the table, for all schedules and all dates (the result is that the table will have twice as many rows). What do you mean by "ALL the schedule rows for a date and only copy them"? What does "only" refer to? In your example, you show copying all the rows.

Comment: I need something like this but it doesn't work if a shift crosses midnight. Perhaps I'll mandate a shift can't cross midnight INSERT into schedule
 ( 
      schedule_id,
       location_id,
       start_date,
       end_date
)
with rws as (
  select s.*,
         max (start_date ) over () mx_dt
  from   schedule s
)
SELECT * from
(
  select schedule_id,
             location_id,
             start_date + 1,
             end_date +1
  from   rws
  where 
    start_date > trunc ( mx_dt )
);